# Save multiple Excel worksheets as indivudual workbooks by cell value and sheet name failure?

Tags: vba, excel

i've searched multiple forums to see if i can discover why a peice of code isnt working but havent found an answer yet.

My VBA isnt great and i inherited this section of code from a predecessor.

This part of the code saves each indivisual worksheet as a new workbook by using the worksheet names.

```
Dim NewBook As Workbook, OldBook As Workbook, sh As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


Set OldBook = ThisWorkbook

For Each sh In OldBook.Worksheets
    If sh.Visible = True Then
        sh.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Pathway" & "\" & sh.Name, FileFormat:=xlExcel8
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

This works fine and will create the sheets for me but I now need to add to the file name by using the same cell value from each worksheet (B1) so i tried adding to the code.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Pathway" & "\" & sh.Range("B1").Value & sh.Name, FileFormat:=xlExcel8
```

However doing so results in a "Run-time error '1004': There is no active Protected View Window" but i'm not too sure why that would be?

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Probably because `Pathway` or `Pathname` is not a valid location

Comment: Hi Tom, sorry i should have said that where i've mentioned "Pathway" i actually have a legitimate one, i just used "Pathway" on here to save typing the whole thing out.

Comment: This code works fine for me - does your pathway end with \ by any chance? Also, what happens to be in range(B1) - does it contain any weird characters?

Comment: What's in cell B1? It may contain some characters which are not allowed in file names.

Comment: Bingo! thanks guys thats cracked it. B1 contained a time but in hh:mm format which of course wouldnt be allowed as a file name. I've since changed it to hh.mm and it works fine. Thanks for your swift input everyone.

Comment: I get this error "There is no Active Protected Window" in a very different situation - it looks like I can now assume that this message is absolutely meaningless...

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to your path not being a string accepted by Windows as file name. As the problem appears when you add B1 to the path, this seems to be the source of your problem. Check if cell B1 contains any characters not allowed in file names.

Comment: Any idea why the error would say "There is no Active Protected Window" - when the actual error is "Invalid file path"...  Though I realize Office has always been negligent with error messages, I'm starting to believe that this message is an internal bug, introduced into Office 2013 in the past few months (because it is meaningless and wrong in this context and I get this error randomly while calculating a sheet)